# Is it possible to disable Plotly showing pie chart textinfo if the value is equal to 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly

I am building a react application that uses Plotly to display some charts. One of the pie charts that contains variables that have value 0. I was wondering can I only show the textinfo the variable that has a value larger than 0.

The current Chart looks like this:
[pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g2xT.png) (I can't embed image in the post)

What I would like to achieve is only showing the 'Radio 100%' text and 'TV 0%' will be hidden.

Current Code Implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

/...rest of code .../

<Plot
    data={[
          {
            values: [100, 0, 0],
            labels: ['Radio, 'TV', 'Newspaper'],
            type: 'pie',
            sort: false,
            textinfo: 'label+percent',
            textposition: 'outside',
            hoverinfo: 'label+percent',
          },
        ]}
    layout={layout}
    config={{ responsive: true }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround I find is set `textposition` to be `inside`, so that the label with 0% would show on the graph. It would be great if plotly can add `auto` to `textposition` variable so label with 0% won't show